# Relationship between User and Comment model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I did relationships between different models all the time but for some reason I can't get this one to work. I tried everything I can find on Google but no luck.

I want to create a relation between Comment and User models. Any user can make many comments and I need to use email address of the commenter.

Basically, this:

```
$comments->user->email
```

My database looks like this:

```
userdata
--- id
--- username
--- email

comments
--- id
--- username
--- comment
```

`userdata.username` and `comments.username` should be related to eachother.

I pass the data to views like this:

```
Comment::with('user')->where('on', $news->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get()
```

No matter what I try, I can't get it to work. Relations are not created. Maybe I came across a strange laravel bug?

Those are my models: (I write the default ones since I messed them up so much trying different approaches)

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    public static $key = 'id';
    protected $table = 'comments';
    public $timestamps = true;
}


class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'userdata';
    public $timestamps = false;

    //It contains necessary imports and methods, I cutted them off for stackoverflow
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal database scheme, docs written [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent). In your case, this should work:

```
// Model: Comment
public function user()
{
    //belongsTo('User', 'local_key', 'parent_key'); so:
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'username', 'username');
}

//Then get this
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    return Comment::find($id)->user->email;
});
```

Comment: Strange enough, it didn't work but I dropped username column on my comments table and replaced it with user_id. That way, it worked. I'll pick your answer as selected regardless.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. You can edit my post if you think other users will benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

This code `$comments->user->email` is not going to work.

`$comments` is an array of comments. It does not hold any shared reference to a user, you will have to pull a particular comment out and read the associated user.

Have you added the `belongsTo()` method to your comment model?

Comment: Well, $comments is an array. I didn't want to include my foreach loop. Normally it is `$comments[$k]->user->email`, or `$v->user->email`